# Woocommerce - change default value tax class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I want change default value `Tax class` it's possible do it when create or update product.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This option looks to come from a plugin. default woocommerce doesn't have that kind of option. what plugin are you using?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I am using only woocommerce.

Comment: Having a look here – the in the absence of good filters/hooks in [this function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dd49f89e77acaaa097251fe0a5dd69320ded48c6/includes/wc-product-functions.php#L823) It's gonna get pretty dicey! Lot of metaboxes to override. This might be more headache than it is worth.

Comment: Can you please be more clear! What you mean by *I want change default value Tax class* ? You want tax calculation for tax-inclusive prices like this `tax_amount = price - (price / ((tax_rate_% / 100 ) + 1))` ? Please add more details what you want. Woocommerce does already all we need.

Comment: @Dlk I wanna change defaut in `<select>`  Tax class

Comment: Ok! what you wanna achive with that ?

Comment: @Dlk For exmaple: change Standart to another one when product is creating

Comment: All your needs in docs here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/#section-2 And This one https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/#section-17 if I understand right.

Comment: @Dlk thank you I 'll checked later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update/change this.

This setting has to enabled Under WooCommerce > Settings > General
[image]

It then this adds the Tax tab.

[image]

Under there you can add additional Tax Classes

[image]

This will add the option to the top of that page to allow you to configure that class.

[image]

This is setup in a way that "standard" is the bulk of your tax that you would collect but could do different ones when needed.

The "standard" doesn't show up to the frontend user so no need to worry about the verbiage.